# stop and remove an autostart docker container

Tags: docker, containers, synology

I have several containers I want to remove. When I stop them, they restart, so I can't remove them. I tried to update them with the command `sudo docker update --restart=no [docker name]` but they are still restarting.

Here is the output of my docker ps :

```
    ~$ sudo docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                            COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS                PORTS                  NAMES
8482a3ba7a1c        homeassistant/amd64-hassio-dns:2021.01.0         "/init"                  About a minute ago   Up About a minute                            hassio_dns
bf6edaa5add5        homeassistant/amd64-hassio-multicast:2021.04.0   "/init"                  8 minutes ago        Up 8 minutes                                 hassio_multicast
f53752b4920f        homeassistant/amd64-hassio-audio:2021.02.1       "/init"                  8 minutes ago        Up 8 minutes                                 hassio_audio
2b5ed16c305d        homeassistant/amd64-hassio-cli:2021.03.1         "/init /bin/bash -c …"   9 minutes ago        Up 9 minutes                                 hassio_cli
27fdf9452c85        homeassistant/amd64-hassio-observer:2020.10.1    "/init"                  9 minutes ago        Up 9 minutes          0.0.0.0:4357->80/tcp   hassio_observer
612417c38db1        homeassistant/amd64-hassio-supervisor            "/init"                  6 days ago           Up 16 minutes                                hassio_supervisor
```

They run on a Synology NAS

Comment: Are you providing the _container id_ or _container name_ to `docker update`? E.g `docker update --restart=no 8482a3ba7a1c` to update the running `homeassistant/amd64-hassio-dns` container's restart policy.

Comment: `docker rm -f <container_name>` might do the trick. If this still doesn't work, since you are on synology, you might simlpy want to use the GUI.

Comment: How were they started?

Comment: None of this works :( I installed them through ssh following a tutorial that I didn't keep. I don't have them in the gui. Containers keeps restarting with all the described method.

Comment: Maybe, your containers are managing by Docker Swarm which is ensure that service running.

Comment: @huytmb that was my first thought, but the container names don't have the extensions added by swarm mode.

Answer (score 2):

Googling for the images you are running, it looks like you may have installed [this supervised tool](https://github.com/home-assistant/supervised-installer):

> This system will run the Home Assistant Supervisor. The Supervisor is not just an application, it is a full appliance that manages the whole system. It will clean up, repair or reset settings to default if they no longer match expected values.

My reading of that is if you remove a container, this tool will probably recreate it.

Reading through the installer script, it runs:

```
systemctl enable hassio-apparmor.service > /dev/null 2>&1;
systemctl start hassio-apparmor.service
```

So to disable, try:

```
systemctl disable hassio-apparmor.service
systemctl stop hassio-apparmor.service
```

Then you can delete the containers (the `-f` runs an initial `docker kill`, this may result in data corruption of any files mounted by these containers):

```
docker container rm -f \
  hassio_dns \
  hassio_multicast \
  hassio_audio \
  hassio_cli \
  hassio_observer \
  hassio_supervisor
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the output of the systemctl command on the synology is : ` ~$ systemctl disable hassio-apparmor.service` `-sh: systemctl: command not found`

Comment: @Nidupb were you root? If that doesn't help, you're going to need to find how you installed these containers to sort out how to uninstall them, because something external is recreating them, from the description, it's not docker itself. Your googling to find it will be better than ours.

Comment: alternative to systemctl try like this, "service hassio-apparmor stop"

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove a container that for whatever reason is not stopping, you can simply use

```
docker rm <container_id> -f
```

This will forcefully stop and remove your container.

Comment: this doesn't work with docker version 24:
`unknown shorthand flag: 'f' in -f`

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! I've fixed the answer, the correct command is `docker rm` and not `docker stop`